# Large Numpy Scipy CSR Matrix, row wise operation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sum

I want to iterate over the rows of a CSR Matrix and divide each element by the sum of the row, similar to this here:

[numpy divide row by row sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202348/numpy-divide-row-by-row-sum)

My problem is that I'm dealing with a large matrix: (96582, 350138)

And when applying the operation from the linked post, it bloats up my memory, since the returned matrix is dense.

So here is my first try:

```
for row in counts:
    row = row / row.sum()
```

Unfortunately this doesn't affect the matrix at all, so I came up with the second idea to create a new csr matrix and concat the rows using vstack:

```
from scipy import sparse
import time

start_time = curr_time = time.time()
mtx = sparse.csr_matrix((0, counts.shape[1]))
for i, row in enumerate(counts):
   prob_row = row / row.sum()
   mtx = sparse.vstack([mtx, prob_row])
   if i % 1000 == 0:
      delta_time = time.time() - curr_time
      total_time = time.time() - start_time
      curr_time = time.time()
      print('step: %i, total time: %i, delta_time: %i' % (i, total_time, delta_time))
```

This works well, but after some iterations it gets slower and slower:

```
step: 0, total time: 0, delta_time: 0
step: 1000, total time: 1, delta_time: 1
step: 2000, total time: 5, delta_time: 4
step: 3000, total time: 12, delta_time: 6
step: 4000, total time: 23, delta_time: 11
step: 5000, total time: 38, delta_time: 14
step: 6000, total time: 55, delta_time: 17
step: 7000, total time: 88, delta_time: 32
step: 8000, total time: 136, delta_time: 47
step: 9000, total time: 190, delta_time: 53
step: 10000, total time: 250, delta_time: 59
step: 11000, total time: 315, delta_time: 65
step: 12000, total time: 386, delta_time: 70
step: 13000, total time: 462, delta_time: 76
step: 14000, total time: 543, delta_time: 81
step: 15000, total time: 630, delta_time: 86
step: 16000, total time: 722, delta_time: 92
step: 17000, total time: 820, delta_time: 97
```

Any suggestions? Any idea why vstack gets slower and slower?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45339754 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/44080315

Comment: As with dense arrays repeated concatenation in a loop is slow.  Accumulating results in a list and doing one `vstack` is faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vstack` is an `O(n)` operation because it needs to allocate memory for the result and then copy the contents of all arrays you passed as arguments into the result array.

You can simply use [`multiply`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.multiply.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.multiply) to do the operation:

```
>>> res = counts.multiply(1 / counts.sum(1))  # multiply with inverse
>>> res.todense()
matrix([[ 0.33333333,  0.        ,  0.66666667],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
        [ 0.26666667,  0.33333333,  0.4       ]])
```

---

But it's also quite easy to use [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) to do the operation you want (relatively performant). This `as_strided` function also allows to do more complicated operations on the array (if there is no method or function for your case).

For example using an example csr of the [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html):

```
>>> from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
>>> import numpy as np
>>> row = np.array([0,0,1,2,2,2])
>>> col = np.array([0,2,2,0,1,2])
>>> data = np.array([1.,2,3,4,5,6])
>>> counts = csr_matrix( (data,(row,col)), shape=(3,3) )
>>> counts.todense()
matrix([[ 1.,  0.,  2.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  3.],
        [ 4.,  5.,  6.]])
```

You can divide each row by it's sum like this:

```
>>> row_start_stop = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(counts.indptr, 
                                                     shape=(counts.shape[0], 2),
                                                     strides=2*counts.indptr.strides)
>>> for start, stop in row_start_stop:   
...    row = counts.data[start:stop]
...    row /= row.sum()
>>> counts.todense()
matrix([[ 0.33333333,  0.        ,  0.66666667],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
        [ 0.26666667,  0.33333333,  0.4       ]])
```

Comment: Great answer, your way of updating the rows is much more efficient than mine. Like a hundred time! This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

## Edit

@MSeifert answer is much more efficient, and that should be the proper way of doing. I think writing `counts[i, :]` implies some column slicing is done which I didn't realize. The documentation explicitly says those are really inefficient operations on csr_matrix. Way have indeed a good example of that.

## Answer

The doc says row slicing is efficient, I think you should do

```
for i in range(counts.shape[0]):
    counts[i,:] /= counts[i,:].sum()
```

This way you edit your matrix in place, it stays sparse and you don't have to use vstack. I'm not sure it is the most efficient operation, but at least you should not have memory issues, and there is no slow down effect as the rows are being computed:

```
import time()
s = time.time()
for i in range(counts.shape[0]):
    counts[i, :] /= (counts[i, :].sum() + 1)
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        e = time.time()
        if i > 0:
            print i, e-s
        s = time.time()
```

## Performances:

`1000 6.00199794769
2000 6.02894091606
3000 7.44459486008
4000 7.10011601448
5000 6.16998195648
6000 7.79510307312
7000 7.00139117241
8000 7.37821507454
9000 7.28075814247
...`

## Performances for MSeifert's answer:

```
row_start_stop = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(counts.indptr, shape=(counts.shape[0], 2),
                                                 strides=2*counts.indptr.strides)
for i, (start, stop) in enumerate(row_start_stop):
    row = counts.data[start:stop]
    row /= row.sum()
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        e = time.time()
        if i > 0:
            print i,e-s
        s = time.time()
```

`1000 0.00735783576965
2000 0.0108380317688
3000 0.0102109909058
4000 0.0131571292877
5000 0.00670218467712
6000 0.00608897209167
7000 0.00663685798645
8000 0.0164499282837
9000 0.0061981678009
...`

As to why using `vstack` is slow, @MSeifert answer is great.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how does the `for item in counts: item /= item.sum()` fare? I am already convinced that the accepted answer should be Mseifert's, this is now personal curiosity for performance difference between implicit and explicit slicing

Comment: The problem with that, is in OP's question. When doing ```for item in counts```, ```item``` isn't really a reference to an actual row of counts. That's why modifying doesn't affect the matrix counts. So I could measure the performances, but I don't really see the point.

Comment: Maybe my understanding of sparse matrices is just not up to scratch. :/ Anyhow, as you can see in my answer, for dense matrices, you can make the reference to the actual row in this way. Thought it'd work in the same manner.. :$

Comment: Yes it does work with with dense matrices, but not for sparse ones. That's what OP says in his question.

Comment: Not true. What OP tries in his question, does not work for dense matrices either..

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. There is indeed a difference when doing ```row /= row.sum()``` and ```row = row/row.sum()```. Absolutely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150412/discussion-between-uvar-and-anis).